# Data filtering on basis on specific record hit and update timings

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table of following nature. The process of transactions on the database where this table resides follows a path where a user can change the delivery date of one, more than one or all of the items. Now, what i want is a set of rows where the user updates the delivery date corresponding to the specific items. You can see that the PO_Number is same for all the items and so is the PO_Date. So, how would the required rows may be queried and displayed?

```
PO_NO        PO_DT      ITEM_CODE  DEL_DATE  UPDATED_ON   OLD_DEL_DATE     NEW_DEL_DATE
======================================================================================== 
01T0012384  20/05/2015  UP01662   24/06/2015  23/5/2015     20/06/2015      24/06/2015
01T0012384  20/05/2015  UP01762   22/06/2015  21/5/2015     20/06/2015      22/06/2015   
01T0012384  20/05/2015  UP01661   24/06/2015  23/5/2015     20/06/2015      24/06/2015 
01T0012384  20/05/2015  UP01763   22/06/2015  21/5/2015     20/06/2015      22/06/2015
```

Please also consider a scenario if the user does his last transaction and updates delivery dates for item_code- (UP01662,UP01661) for a (say)10th time on a day. Then in the end all i want is a query which fetches data-sets for only these two items and nothing else.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need. If the data you posted are a needed result, can you please post the starting data? Or, if this is the starting data, what should the result be?

Comment: Please guys let me know if i need to elaborate the problem here.
I really need a solution for this.

Comment: This is the starting data. I will elaborate the flow for you. 

A user updates the given data through a form and the column effected are - UPDATED_ON, OLD_DEL_DATE and NEW_DEL_DATE.

 Now, there is trigger created that gets fired upon each updation and that trigger should fetch those rows for which these three columns have been updated.

There may be a number of scenarios , for example, a user updates on two items for the order. So, the query should fetch only those two rows not any other row.

Now, if you have any questions regarding "the question"?

Comment: What is your Oracle version? In 12c there is [`match_recognize`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm) for specifying patterns in a sequence of rows.

Comment: No brother. I am using 11g as of now.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: A record set of affected rows after each update, but only through sql and not plsql.
Its a compulsion.

Answer (score 0):

i think this might help u a little https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a0742b7-b976-42b7-8230-4ae46441a63a/when-was-the-last-time-a-record-was-addedmodified-in-a-sql-table?forum=transactsql

```
 declare @objectid int
    select @objectid = object_id from sys.objects where name = 'YOURTABLENAME'

    select top 1 * from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats where object_id = @objectid
    and last_user_update is not null
    order by last_user_update
```

Comment: This is not Oracle

Comment: @venky513  I need to do this in oracle sql, sql server is not questoin here.
Still thanks for considering the problem. It would be great if you could provide a solution for oracle sql.

Comment: @Aleksej

yes, can you provide one?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to create your custom function to check if any column was changed and an after update trigger. If you know some columns that must always change with every update than this is even easier to check if your row was changed or not - otherwise you have to check all columns from user_tab_columns for your table.

For the generic approach, please check: 
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055

Comment: UPDATED_ON column changes for each row whenever it is updated.
The problem is to fetch the rows affected through a separate query which can be a function, a procedure or a cursor. Please also tell me if :old and :new can be used in a general query other than using in a trigger.

Comment: From the provided link: :new and :old are like bind variables to the trigger, they are not 'regular' variables. you cannot dynamically access them. If you want to have a function not called by trigger, then when/what calls it? And it would check if any record was change since when? You could either store the last time you checked or mirror the table image and check against it.

Comment: The issue is not the trigger brother. All i need is a query that can fetch the last updated rows and nothing else. This is the most simple way i can put it.

Comment: You must define what "last updated rows" mean. This could mean: updated since last time you checked OR updated today OR last 100 records updated OR .. Anyway, you have as options:  triggers (best option), ORA_ROWSCN which will give you (aprox.) the last DML operation on record, flashback queries, check of redolog, etc.

Comment: The user keeps updating the DEL_DATE column (added in the above table structure) from front end. Suppose he/she updates the delivery date only for item number UP01662. Then the query should only fetch me the result set containing the data regarding that item only and no other.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this is what you need.

```
create table xx_ap_orders (  po_number varchar2(10)
                            , item_code  varchar2(10)
                            , amount number
                            , updated_date date
                           );
```

So, the scenario is:

all records were updated 5 days ago

row with MOUSE item code was updated 4 days ago

CABLE and BATERY item codes were updated 2 days ago.

Records in table would look like:

```
insert into xx_ap_orders values ('PO_500','LAPTOP', 3500, trunc (sysdate - 5) );
insert into xx_ap_orders values ('PO_500','MOUSE',   200, trunc (sysdate - 4) );
insert into xx_ap_orders values ('PO_500','CABLE',   100, trunc (sysdate - 2) );
insert into xx_ap_orders values ('PO_500','BATERY',  500, trunc (sysdate - 2) );
```

If you would like to select only CABLE and BATERY records (the last updated) you have the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT po_number
       , item_code
       , amount
       , updated_date
       , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY po_number
                     order by updated_date desc) rank_updated
FROM XX_AP_ORDERS)
WHERE rank_updated = 1
;
```

Comment: great effort @Alex. But this solutions just falls short by a step. When i updated the UPDATED_DATE column first time then everything goes well and only the effected rows is fetched through the query provided by you. But the solution fails to fulfill my requirement when i  update any other item (during second updation). Suppose, i updated only one row in the first round ,(say) 'BATERY'. I run the query, smooth result with one row.

Comment: Next round and i update 'LAPTOP' AND 'MOUSE' and then run the query, the result fetched has now 3 rows including the row updated in the first round. What i need is that after each round running the query should return only rows affected / in that round only and not in previous rounds.

Comment: UPDATE xx_ap_orders

  SET amount = amount +50 

    , updated_Date = sysdate;
-- run the query: all 4 records fetched

UPDATE xx_ap_orders
  SET amount = amount - 50
    , updated_Date = sysdate
WHERE ITEM_CODE IN ( 'MOUSE','CABLE');

-- run the query: 2 records fetched

Comment: Please share the way you are updating the records..  the provided sql will bring you: all records having the updated_date = max(updated_date) for each po_number.  If you say it returned to many rows after 2nd round of updates its because you didn't provide different value for updated_date.

Comment: i am updating the records through an oracle form which updates the del_date and updated_on columns on item level. I can update any item for any number of time in a single day and it should fetch me (every time) those rows for which the updation had took place

Comment: If your **updated_on** column is truncated at day level, then all records with same updated_on are within an update cycle. The SQL that I provided you works fine. If you want multiple update iterations within same day and you want to make a difference between them, then don't truncate the **update_on** column. Please spool content of the table for which you consider that provided SQL doesn't work

Comment: The column in question is not truncated at day level. Problem, my brother, is that your query does mot differentiate data  in second cycle (when the query hits for second time after updation). I do not need data that was returned by the query in the first cycle to be fetched again in the second cycle along with the results on second cycle.

Comment: Please provide scenario with: exact content of table, DML operations executed on each cycle and expected result on each cycle